# Why my Stepper Component in Vuetify display none?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm use Vue and Axios to show data using Stepper Component from Vuetify. So after add the API data have but CSS class set to `display: none;`. I don't know why, please help me.

This is my code to show data. If you want anything please tell me

```
 <v-stepper v-model="questionTab">
                            <v-stepper-items>
                                    <text-component
                                        v-for="item in question_data" :key="item.questionTab"
                                        :stepData="1"
                                        :questionid="item.questions.question_title"
                                        :questiondescription="item.questions.question_desc"
                                    ></text-component>
                            </v-stepper-items>
                        </v-stepper>
```

Comment: Could you please show your text-component?

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap your `text-component` inside a `v-stepper-content` component.

https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/steppers/

```
<template>
  <v-stepper v-model="questionTab">
        <v-stepper-header>
            <v-stepper-step
            v-for="(item, idx) in question_data"
            :key="idx"
            :complete="model > idx+1"
            >
                Name of Step {{ idx + 1 }}
            </v-stepper-step>
        </v-stepper-header>

        <v-stepper-items>
            <v-stepper-content 
            v-for="(item, idx) in question_data" 
            :key="item.questionTab"
            :step="idx+1">
                <text-component
                    :stepData="1"
                    :questionid="item.questions.question_title"
                    :questiondescription="item.questions.question_desc"
                ></text-component>
            </v-stepper-content>
        </v-stepper-items>
    </v-stepper>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem and solved it by jumping to that newly added step not immediately but using `$nextTick`

```
addStep() {
  const index = this.currentStep;
  this.steps.splice(index, 0, {
    name: '',
    image: '',
    command: '',
    args: '',
  });
  this.$nextTick(() => {
    this.currentStep += 1;
  });
},
```